# i want to create the summary report in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, summary

Get the column names and their corresponding data types in a summarise  order

code:
1. `col_dtype=pd.DataFrame(customer_final.dtypes)` //first i got the column datatype
2. `col_name=pd.DataFrame(customer_final.columns)` //then i got the column names separately because i want to display summary report
3. `pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([col_name,col_dtype],axis=1).values,columns=['columns','datatype'])`

report is generating in this way:

[![Column Name  Datatype
0   customer_Id NaN
1   DOB NaN
2   Gender  NaN
3   city_code   NaN
4   transaction_id  NaN
5   cust_id NaN
6   tran_date   NaN
7   prod_subcat_code    NaN
8   prod_cat_code   NaN
9   Qty NaN
10  Rate    NaN
11  Tax NaN
12  total_amt   NaN
13  Store_type  NaN
14  prod_cat    NaN
15  prod_sub_cat_code   NaN
16  prod_subcat NaN
17  NaN object
18  NaN object
19  NaN int64
20  NaN int64
21  NaN object
22  NaN float64
23  NaN float64
24  NaN int64
25  NaN int64
26  NaN object
27  NaN int64
28  NaN int64
29  NaN object
30  NaN int64
31  NaN float64
32  NaN object
33  NaN int64][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsNFH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsNFH.png)

Comment: sorry for the format ,i also added the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dtypes` attribute returns a pandas series with the column names as index, so you can just do this:

```
columns_summary_df = customer_final.dtypes.reset_index()
columns_summary_df.columns = ['columns', 'datatype']
```